# Modifying code from binary classifier logistic regression to multi-class "one vs all" logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression

Im new to machine learning and trying to practice different algorithms, currently Im classifying a random dataset generated from sklearn with Logistic Regression. Right now this is a binary classifier, however I would like to use a multi-class Logistic Regression "one vs all" approach (for comparison later).

Below is the code I have tried to implement for binary classification:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
import random
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, t = make_blobs(n_samples=[400, 800, 400], centers=[[0,0], [1,2], [2,3]],
                  n_features=2, random_state=2019)

indices = np.arange(X.shape[0])
random.seed(2020)
random.shuffle(indices)
indices[:10]

X_train = X[indices[:800], :]
X_val = X[indices[800:1200], :]
X_test = X[indices[1200:], :]
t_train = t[indices[:800]]
t_val = t[indices[800:1200]]
t_test = t[indices[1200:]]

t2_train = t_train == 1
t2_train = t2_train.astype('int')
t2_val = (t_val == 1).astype('int')
t2_test = (t_test == 1).astype('int')

def add_bias(X):
    # Put bias in position 0
    sh = X.shape
    if len(sh) == 1:
        #X is a vector
        return np.concatenate([np.array([1]), X])
    else:
        # X is a matrix
        m = sh[0]
        bias = np.ones((m, 1)) # Makes a m*1 matrix of 1-s
        return np.concatenate([bias, X], axis  = 1)

class NumpyClassifier():
    # Common methods to all numpy classifiers --- if any

    def accuracy(self, X_val, t_val, **kwargs):
        pred = self.predict(X_val, **kwargs)
        if len(pred.shape) > 1:
            pred = pred[:, 0]
        return sum(pred==t_val)/len(pred)

# code for Logistic Regression
def logistic(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

class NumpyLogReg(NumpyClassifier):

    def fit(self, X_train, t_train, gamma = 0.1, epochs=10):
        # X_train is a Nxm matrix, N data points, m features
        # t_train are the targets values for training data

        (k, m) = X_train.shape
        X_train = add_bias(X_train)

        self.theta = theta = np.zeros(m+1)

        for e in range(epochs):
            theta -= gamma / k *  X_train.T @ (self.forward(X_train) - t_train)

    def forward(self, X_val):
        return logistic(X_val @ self.theta)

    def score(self, X_val):
        z = add_bias(X_val)
        score = self.forward(z)
        return score

    def predict(self, X_val, threshold=0.5):
        z = add_bias(X_val)
        score = self.forward(z)
        # score = z @ self.theta
        return (score>threshold).astype('int')

lr_cl = NumpyLogReg()
lr_cl.fit(X_train, t_train)
lr_cl.predict(X_val)
lr_cl.accuracy(X_val, t_val)

for e in [1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    lr_cl = NumpyLogReg()
    lr_cl.fit(X_train, t_train, epochs=e, gamma=0.00001)
    print("{:10}  {:7.3f}".format(e, lr_cl.accuracy(X_val, t_val)))
```

I need advice/ tips on how I can modify the code into a multi-class "one vs all"/ "one vs rest" Logistic Regression.
I dont want to use sklearn imported logistic regression algorithm directly, rather do it from scratch like this.

Any advice is highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `NumpyLogReg` works very well on binary classification. Make use of the same class for `multi-class` classification using the `One-Vs-Rest` (ovr) technique.

Let's assume the dataset is having 3 classes `A, B, C`

1. Call the binary classification model with the class label `A` as +ve class & `B, C` as -ve class and note down the prob scores
2. Repeat the same by considering `B` as +ve & `A, C` as -ve and `C` as +ve & `A, B` as -ve. Note down the respective prob scores.
3. Basically, if there are `n` classes, there will be `n` binary classifier models i.e, `fitting one classifier per class`
4. By careful inspection of the classifier of each of the classes (i.e., by analyzing the prob values), you can achieve `multi-class` classification & the model will be highly interpretable.

Please refer [this guideline](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html#ovr-classification) for more detailed explanation